# Excel VSTO add-in : Can I disable Excel Headings in code?

Tags: excel, vsto

I'm building a Visual Studio workbook add-in component for Excel (2007+). I have a few worksheets in my VSTO-modified workbook that I want to disable the Headings in code. (what you can do in the Excel ribbon > View > Headings 'checkbox'). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VB.Net

```
Me.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
```

> C #

```
this.Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = false;
```

Comment: Perfect. Why was I think it would be on the sheet.